# Automatically wrap a macro

Tags: macros

Is it possible to automatically wrap a macro with its arguments? (or at least do that for macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, as I guess it might be hard to do it for any macro?) I would like my user to type:

```
\wrapMyMacro{somearbitrarymacro}{some options}

\somearbitrarymacro{foo}[bar]
```

an translate this into:

```
\cacheMe[some options]{
  \somearbitrarymacro{foo}[bar]
}
```

I would also add an optional argument enclosed into `<>`the macro, so that typing:

```
\somearbitrarymacro<more options>{foo}[bar]
```

would translate into:

```
\cacheMe[some options, more options]{
  \somearbitrarymacro{foo}[bar]
}
```

Is it possible? I guess I can manage to obtain this result as soon as I manage to obtain the list of options of the macro into a string, like |{foo}[bar]|.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%% My library
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cacheMe}{O{}m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmp_str {#2}
  We ~ will ~ cache ~ \texttt{\l_tmp_str} ~ with ~ options ~ \texttt{#1}.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% Arbitrary macro I don't know the definition

\NewDocumentCommand{\somearbitrarymacro}{mO{}}{
  My arbitrary (#2) macro says ``#1''.
}

%% User ca

\begin{document}

\somearbitrarymacro{hey alice}[options]

\cacheMe[cache options1, cache options2]{\somearbitrarymacro{hey alice}[options]}

%%% How to get this same result using:
% \wrapMyMacro{somearbitrarymacro}{cache options1}
% \somearbitrarymacro{hey alice}[options]
% \somearbitrarymacro<cache options2>{hey alice}[options]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** I thought that this solution was working, but in fact it is not. Notably, weird things happen with the arguments: if I use tokenize, then I cannot use the result with `pgfkeys`, and without tokenize it expands directly the arguments too early or double the number of hashes… but for the reference here is my try:

I realized that this cool library has this feature, so I adapted the code from here https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize. I don't know if the code can be improved, but seems to work for now.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xparse-arglist} %% copy .sty from https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize/blob/master/xparse-arglist.sty


%% My library
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cacheMe}{O{}m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmp_str {#2}
  We ~ will ~ cache ~ \texttt{\l_tmp_str} ~ with ~ options ~ \texttt{#1}.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% Arbitrary macro I don't know the definition

\NewDocumentCommand{\somearbitrarymacro}{mO{coucou}D<>{ahah}}{
  My arbitrary (#2) macro says ``#1'' with a last argument (#3).
}


\begin{document}

\somearbitrarymacro{hey alice}[options]

\cacheMe[cache options1, cache options2]{\somearbitrarymacro{hey alice}[options]}

%%% How to get this same result using:

%% User ca

\makeatletter

%% The idea of the library is that it builds a string like
%% [#2]<#3>{#4}
%% in order to generate something like
%% \NewDocumentCommand{\myfunction}{D<>{}O{coucou}D<>{yes}m}
%% {
%%  \cacheMe[#1]{\myfunction[#2]<#3>{#4}}
%% }
%% Since the very first occurrence of D is not forwarded to the function
%% we discard it:
%% The first argument of \xp@arglist@D is the number of the argument
%% so #2#####1#3 reads as #2 = <, #### = #, #1 = > #3 = value if none that can be discarded since it is already part of the argument spec.
\def\xp@arglist@D#1#2#3#4{%
  \noexpand\unexpanded{%
    \ifnum #1=1 % If it is the first argument D, then we do not add anything to the argument string
    \else #2#####1#3\fi}\xp@arglist{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cacheCommand}{mom}{%
  %% We get the specification of the command, like "O{}mm"
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \expandafter\GetDocumentCommandArgSpec\csname #1\endcsname%
  }{%
    \def\ArgumentSpecification{#2}
  }%
  \edef\ArgumentSpecification{D<>{}\ArgumentSpecification}
  \edef\mmz@marshal{%
    \noexpand\DeclareDocumentCommand
      \expandonce{\csname #1\endcsname}%
      {\expandonce{\ArgumentSpecification}}%
      {%
        % todo: add a hook for users setup; prevent user from changing \MemoizeWrapper?
        \edef\noexpand\mmz@marshal{%
        \noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\cacheMe[#3,####1]{%
          \noexpand\noexpand\expandonce{\csname #1\endcsname}%
            \ArgumentList
        }%
      }\noexpand\mmz@marshal
    }%
  }\mmz@marshal
}


\makeatother


\ExplSyntaxOff

\cacheCommand{somearbitrarymacro}{global options}
\somearbitrarymacro{hey Bob}[options]
\somearbitrarymacro{Default charlie}
\somearbitrarymacro<local options>{hey alice}[INTERNAL options]<Last arg>

\end{document}
```

For reference, the .sty file contains:

```
\ProvidesPackage{xparse-arglist}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\def\ArgumentList{%
  \expandafter\xp@arglist\expandafter0\ArgumentSpecification.%
}

\def\xp@arglist#1#2{%
  \ifcsname xp@arglist@#2\endcsname
    \csname xp@arglist@#2\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
  \else
    \expandafter\xp@arglist@error
  \fi
  \expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}%
}

% \xp@arglist@...: #1 = the argument number
\def\xp@arglist@m#1{\noexpand\unexpanded{{#####1}}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@r#1#2#3{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2#####1#3}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@R#1#2#3#4{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2#####1#3}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@v#1{{Handled commands with verbatim arguments are not
    supported}\xp@arglist{#1}} % error
\def\xp@arglist@b#1{{This is not the way to handle
    environment}\xp@arglist{#1}} % error
\def\xp@arglist@o#1{\noexpand\unexpanded{[#####1]}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@d#1#2#3{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2#####1#3}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@O#1#2{\noexpand\unexpanded{[#####1]}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@D#1#2#3#4{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2#####1#3}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@s#1{\noexpand\IfBooleanT{#####1}{*}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@t#1#2{\noexpand\IfBooleanT{#####1}{#2}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\csdef{xp@arglist@+}#1{\expandafter\xp@arglist\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}}%
\csdef{xp@arglist@.}#1{}
% e,E: Embellishments are not supported.
% > Argument processors are not supported. And how could they be?
\def\xp@arglist@error#1.{{Unknown argument type}}
```

Comment: And why would you want that?

Comment: Anyway, isn’t this just a matter of having a macro with options (e.g. using keyval syntax) and then letting `\wrapMyMacro` set up these options globally, and `<...>` set them up locally?

Comment: @Gaussler It is for my library robust-externalize to cache arbitrary content. I made a code to cache automatically arbitrary environments like `\cacheEnvironment{tikzpictures}{some options}`, but no idea how to do the same for commands. The actual process is quite complicated, see page 53, option 2 of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/master/doc/robust-externalize.pdf The code for environments is at https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/blob/718f90333b9a1c8422512cd3af00237c20b38bc2/robust-externalize.sty#L1513

Comment: @Gaussle I'm not sure to see what you mean: so macro to wrap could be anything like `tikz` and I'd like to wrap it with `\cacheCommand{tikz}{some options}`

Comment: What to do in case `\somearbitrarymacro`, e.g., initializes a tail-recursive loop where the amount of arguments processed is not pre-determined by the <parameter text> of the <definition>? E.g., `\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}\def\somearbitrarymacro#1{\ifnum\numexpr(#1)\relax>0 \exchange{\processnextarg{#1}}\fi}\def\processnextarg#1#2{Arg in this iteration is: (#2) \expandafter\somearbitrarymacro\expandafter{\the\numexpr(#1)-1\relax}}\somearbitrarymacro{3}{One}{Two}{Three}\bye`

Comment: The macros underlying an environment could be defined in the same way for processing an arbitrary amount of arguments before processing the environment-body.

Comment: @UlrichDiez in this case the user can be asked to manually wrap the content, but it is quite rare. (And for environments, my current code should already take care of this case.) I'm fine with giving an advice like "the structure of the macro is O{}mm". I just realized that people have done it before in https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize, xparse-arglist.sty seems to contain most of the magic. Don't know if a library is present in CTAN now to deal with that case without boilerplate code.

Comment: In the past, when xparse wasn't integrated into the LaTeX 2e-kernel yet, the xparse-manual said, that argument-specifications of document commands and document environments can be obtained via `\GetDocumentCommandArgSpec` / `\GetDocumentEnvironmentArgSpec`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes, this is how I actually access this information in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to avoid my issues by wrapping the arguments in a `\tl_rescan` that correctly parses the `#`… hopefully this time I got all edge cases.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xparse-arglist} %% copy .sty from https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize/blob/master/xparse-arglist.sty


%% My library
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cacheMe}{O{}m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmp_str {#2}
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmp_opt_str {#1}
  We ~ will ~ cache ~ \texttt{\l_tmp_str} ~ with ~ options ~ \texttt{\l_tmp_opt_str}.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% Arbitrary macro I don't know the definition

\NewDocumentCommand{\somearbitrarymacro}{mO{coucou}D<>{ahah}}{
  My arbitrary (#2) macro says ``#1'' with a last argument (#3).
}


\begin{document}


\newcommand{\myMacroNotDefinedWithNewDocumentCommand}[3][default value]{
  Optional argument 1: #1,
  Argument 2: #2,
  Argument 3: #3 (\fromWhere).
}


% \somearbitrarymacro{hey alice}[options]

% \cacheMe[cache options1, cache options2]{\somearbitrarymacro{hey alice}[options]}

%%% How to get this same result using:

%% User ca

\makeatletter

%% The idea of the library is that it builds a string like
%% [#2]<#3>{#4}
%% in order to generate something like
%% \NewDocumentCommand{\myfunction}{D<>{}O{coucou}D<>{yes}m}
%% {
%%  \cacheMe[#1]{\myfunction[#2]<#3>{#4}}
%% }
%% Since the very first occurrence of D is not forwarded to the function
%% we discard it:
%% The first argument of \xp@arglist@D is the number of the argument
%% so #2#####1#3 reads as #2 = <, #### = #, #1 = > #3 = value if none that can be discarded since it is already part of the argument spec.
\def\xp@arglist@D#1#2#3#4{%
  \noexpand\unexpanded{%
    \ifnum #1=1 % If it is the first argument D, then we do not add anything to the argument string
    \else #2#####1#3\fi}\xp@arglist{#1}%
}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn { Nnx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn { cnx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn { cxx }
\cs_set:Nn \str_set_hash_robust:Nn {
  \str_set:Nn {#1} {#2}
  \str_replace_all:Nnx {#1} { ## } { \c_hash_str }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set_hash_robust:Nn { cn }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set_hash_robust:Nn { cx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\tl_rescan:nn { nv }

\NewDocumentCommand{\robExtRescanAndHalveHashes}{m}{
  \str_set_hash_robust:Nn \l_robExt_tmp_str {#1}
  \show\l_robExt_tmp_str
  \tl_rescan:nv {}{ l_robExt_tmp_str }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


%% After the first expansion, this will look like:
% \DeclareDocumentCommand \myMacroNotDefinedWithNewDocumentCommand {D<>{}O{default value}mm}{
%   \edef \mmz@marshal {
%     \noexpand \cacheMe [latex,#1]{
%       \noexpand \myMacroNotDefinedWithNewDocumentCommand \unexpanded {}\unexpanded {[#2]}\unexpanded {{#3}}\unexpanded {{#4}}
%     }
%   }
%     \show\mmz@marshal
%   % <--- this will be equal after the second expansion to:
%   % \cacheMe [latex,]{ \myMacroNotDefinedWithNewDocumentCommand [default value]{Second arg}{Last arg} }
%   \mmz@marshal
% }
\NewDocumentCommand{\cacheCommand}{mom}{%
  %% We get the specification of the command, like "O{}mm"
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \expandafter\GetDocumentCommandArgSpec\csname #1\endcsname%
  }{%
    \def\ArgumentSpecification{#2}%
  }%
  \edef\ArgumentSpecification{D<>{}\ArgumentSpecification}%
  \edef\mmz@marshal{%
    \noexpand\DeclareDocumentCommand%
      \expandonce{\csname #1\endcsname}%
      {\expandonce{\ArgumentSpecification}}%
      {%
        % todo: add a hook for users setup; prevent user from changing \MemoizeWrapper?
        \edef\noexpand\mmz@marshal{%
        \noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\robExtRescanAndHalveHashes{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\cacheMe[\detokenize{#3}, \noexpand\detokenize{####1}]{%
          \noexpand\noexpand\expandonce{\csname #1\endcsname}%
            \ArgumentList%
          }%
        }%
      }%
      % For debug
      %\noexpand\show\noexpand\mmz@marshal
      \noexpand\mmz@marshal%
    }%
  }%
  % for debug
  %\show\mmz@marshal%
  \mmz@marshal%
}


\makeatother


\ExplSyntaxOff

\cacheCommand{somearbitrarymacro}{global options}
\somearbitrarymacro{hey Bob}[options]
\somearbitrarymacro{Default charlie}
\somearbitrarymacro<local options>{hey alice}[INTERNAL options]<Last arg>

\cacheCommand{myMacroNotDefinedWithNewDocumentCommand}[O{default value}mm]{latex, \latex}
\myMacroNotDefinedWithNewDocumentCommand{Second arg}{Last arg}\\
\myMacroNotDefinedWithNewDocumentCommand<disable externalization>{second arg}{last arg}

\end{document}
```

For reference, the .sty file contains:

```
\ProvidesPackage{xparse-arglist}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\def\ArgumentList{%
  \expandafter\xp@arglist\expandafter0\ArgumentSpecification.%
}

\def\xp@arglist#1#2{%
  \ifcsname xp@arglist@#2\endcsname
    \csname xp@arglist@#2\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
  \else
    \expandafter\xp@arglist@error
  \fi
  \expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}%
}

% \xp@arglist@...: #1 = the argument number
\def\xp@arglist@m#1{\noexpand\unexpanded{{#####1}}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@r#1#2#3{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2#####1#3}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@R#1#2#3#4{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2#####1#3}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@v#1{{Handled commands with verbatim arguments are not
    supported}\xp@arglist{#1}} % error
\def\xp@arglist@b#1{{This is not the way to handle
    environment}\xp@arglist{#1}} % error
\def\xp@arglist@o#1{\noexpand\unexpanded{[#####1]}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@d#1#2#3{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2#####1#3}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@O#1#2{\noexpand\unexpanded{[#####1]}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@D#1#2#3#4{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2#####1#3}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@s#1{\noexpand\IfBooleanT{#####1}{*}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\def\xp@arglist@t#1#2{\noexpand\IfBooleanT{#####1}{#2}\xp@arglist{#1}}
\csdef{xp@arglist@+}#1{\expandafter\xp@arglist\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}}%
\csdef{xp@arglist@.}#1{}
% e,E: Embellishments are not supported.
% > Argument processors are not supported. And how could they be?
\def\xp@arglist@error#1.{{Unknown argument type}}
```